# Monitor disconnects on sleep

Tags: display, hdmi

I have a Dell XPS 13 9370 running Ubuntu 16.04 with a monitor connected via a USB-C to HDMI adaptor. This works fine when I boot the laptop, but if the laptop wakes from sleep, the attached monitor doesn't display. The screen still shows as connected under screen display, but no signal is being sent to the monitor. The only way I can find to get it to start sending a signal is to physical disconnect the HDMI cable from the monitor and then plug it back in again. Turning the screen off and on in Screen Display doesn't cause it to show.

Is there any way to resolve the issue when waking from sleep? As a second best option, is there any command I can run which will simulate the HDMI disconnect so I don't have to physical unplug the cable each time?